# Codewars Permutations Kata - .sort() method that returns 0.5 - Math.random()

Tags: javascript

I am completing the Permutations kata on Codewars.com and have come across this line of code in my investigation (irrelevant I know or at least I think I know):

```
function permutations(string) {
  let arrayPerm = string.split('');
  let cbFunc = function (){ 
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
  };
  arrayPerm.sort(cbFunc);
  console.log(arrayPerm);
}

permutations('abab');
```

Can someone please advise on what is happening in lines 3-6?

Comment: That is a way to sort an array in random order.  Normally, a sort would be comparing two adjacent values in the array and returning -1 or 1 depending on which is greater in value.  This function just generates a random number between -0.5 and 0.5 instead.  It doesn't matter too much what the values actually are as long as they are either negative or positive.

Comment: but do they have to be the same numbers? and do they have to have a difference of 1?

Comment: They will be random numbers - anything between -0.5 and +0.5. The actual values are irrelevant - it's the -/+ bit that's important.  Normally, a sort function would return a -/+ number or true/false.  The effect is the same, it tells the sort to either keep the pair of adjacent items as they are or to swap them.  So, the difference could be 1,000,000 or 0.1 - it doesn't really matter.  Typically, you will see `a - b` - this will result in either -n, +n or 0 (where `n` is **any** number).  If n is < 0, a is less than b.  If n > 0, a is greater than b - so the pair are swapped.

Comment: ....  One advantage of using random numbers is that you can give priority to certain items in your array.  Your example should generate a fairly even split between negatives and positives because the `0.5` is hard-coded and the random number will be between 0 and 1.  But, it doesn't have to be hard-coded - it could be any value between 0 and 1 and determined by a property value of either `a` or `b`.  Thus, if something on `a` makes it more important, you reduce `0.5` to, say, `0.1` and it is much more likely to produce a negative and leave `a` before `b` in the sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

It's randomly sorting elements. By taking `Math.random()` (`0 <= n < 1`) from `0.5`, the sort compare function randomly returns less than or greater than 0 (or technically 0 if we happen to magically get 0.5 at random) to determine element ordering.

You can read about the sort compare function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: ive seen that article and how the `.sort((a, b) => a - b) ` works .. so that 0.5 number can really be any number right? for eg. whats the diff between `0.5 - Math.random()` and `3 - Math.random()` ?

Comment: It could yes, but `3 - Math.random()` would always be greater than 0 as `Math.random()` returns `0 <= N < 1` and it wouldn't be 'random' anymore. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random